# Selecting last observations of each item R

Tags: r

The database (below an extract) consist of companies for which each observation contains info about companies for one year. Each company has a unique identifier "gvkey" (first column). The variable "costat" may take two forms "A" or "I".

I would like to select the last observation for each company with the value "I" in the variable "costat" and count the number of times each of the values in column "dlrsn" comes up per year (column "year"). The variable "dlrsn" can take number from 1 to 14. I want to know how many times each number comes up every year (column "year") after selecting the last observation for each company.

Expected output assuming there would be only 5 years and two possible values for "dlrsn":

```
year dlrsn1 dlrsn2
1 1977      1      0
2 1989      0     1
```

where dlrsn1 = 9 (as in the data) and dlrsn2 = 7.

Dataframe below

```
    dput(example)
structure(list(gvkey = c(1000L, 1000L, 1000L, 1000L, 1000L, 1003L, 
1003L, 1003L, 1003L, 1003L, 1003L, 1003L, 1004L, 1004L, 1004L, 
1004L, 1004L, 1004L, 1004L, 1004L, 1004L, 1004L, 1004L, 1004L, 
1004L, 1004L, 1004L, 1004L, 1004L, 1004L), fyear = c(1973L, 1974L, 
1975L, 1976L, 1977L, 1983L, 1984L, 1985L, 1986L, 1987L, 1988L, 
1989L, 1973L, 1974L, 1975L, 1976L, 1977L, 1978L, 1979L, 1980L, 
1981L, 1982L, 1983L, 1984L, 1985L, 1986L, 1987L, 1988L, 1989L, 
1990L), costat = c("I", "I", "I", "I", "I", "I", "I", "I", "I", 
"I", "I", "I", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", 
"A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A"), dlrsn = c(9L, 9L, 9L, 
9L, 9L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), sale = c(37.75, 
50.325, 51.192, 66.414, 77.946, 13.793, 13.829, 24.189, 36.308, 
37.356, 32.808, 19.267, 57.312, 54.626, 65.797, 80.535, 92.82, 
118.667, 130.617, 132.482, 175.924, 155.006, 177.762, 218.946, 
248.012, 298.192, 347.64, 406.36, 444.875, 466.542)), row.names = c(NA, 
-30L), class = "data.frame")
```

I am not sure how to even start. Thank you

Comment: Consider the word “minimal” in “minimal reproducible example”. As an incentive, please supply the output you expect based on your test data.

Comment: Assuming there would be only 5 years and two possible values for column dlrsn, I expect something like this that then I can use for a bar plot:

`year dlrsn1 dlrsn2
1 1984      8      7
2 1985      5     27
3 1986     10     10
4 1987     30     25
5 1988     26     45
`

Comment: But there are at least 5 possible values of `dlrsn` (`9`, `7`, `NA`, `1` and `10`) in your test data, so your suggested output is not consistent with the input you provided.  Voting to close for lack of reproducibility.  If you make your input and output consistent, I may retract.

Comment: I tried to make changes to minimize the input and make the expected output consistent to it. 
Once only companies with "costat" = "I", the dlrsn cannot take value NA.

Answer (score 0):

With `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)

dt2 <- dcast(
  setorder(
    setDT(dt),
    gvkey, fyear # make sure it's ordered by gvkey and fyear
  )[
    costat == "I", # select only rows with costat = "I
    .(year = fyear[.N], dlrsn = dlrsn[.N]), # get the last observation
    gvkey # group by gvkey
  ],
  year~dlrsn, length, value.var = "dlrsn" # cast long to wide by dlrsn count
)

setnames(dt2, names(dt2)[-1], paste0("dlrsn", names(dt2)[-1]))[] # rename columns
#>    year dlrsn7 dlrsn9
#> 1: 1977      0      1
#> 2: 1989      1      0
```

Data:

```
dt <- data.frame(
  gvkey = c(1000L, 1000L, 1000L, 1000L, 1000L, 1003L, 
            1003L, 1003L, 1003L, 1003L, 1003L, 1003L, 1004L, 1004L, 1004L, 
            1004L, 1004L, 1004L, 1004L, 1004L, 1004L, 1004L, 1004L, 1004L, 
            1004L, 1004L, 1004L, 1004L, 1004L, 1004L),
  fyear = c(1973L, 1974L, 
            1975L, 1976L, 1977L, 1983L, 1984L, 1985L, 1986L, 1987L, 1988L, 
            1989L, 1973L, 1974L, 1975L, 1976L, 1977L, 1978L, 1979L, 1980L, 
            1981L, 1982L, 1983L, 1984L, 1985L, 1986L, 1987L, 1988L, 1989L, 
            1990L), 
  costat = c("I", "I", "I", "I", "I", "I", "I", "I", "I", 
             "I", "I", "I", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", 
             "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A"), 
  dlrsn = c(9L, 9L, 9L, 
            9L, 9L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
            NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)
)
```

Comment: Thank you this works.

I was also wondering if one could use dplyr

Comment: The best way to get a dplyr-specific answer is to add it as a tag and mention it in the question.